# MMQGIS Plugin not working with QGIS 2.6.1? (Resolved)

Tags: qgis, mmqgis

QGIS 2.6.1 on Windows
Have done a bit of research on this and I think it may be caused by the recent update in version to QGIS 2.6 (it worked in 2.4).
I am trying to perform an attribute join from csv using the mmqgis plugin but I get the following error.

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:/Users/ben.glover/.qgis2/python/plugins\mmqgis\mmqgis_dialogs.py", line 278, in run
>       joinattribute, outfilename, notfoundname, 1)
>     File "C:/Users/ben.glover/.qgis2/python/plugins\mmqgis\mmqgis_library.py", line 900, in mmqgis_attribute_join
>       if row[join_index].strip().lower() == key:
>   IndexError: list index out of range

Can anyone confirm that this is caused by the update in version- maybe someone can give it a try?

Comment: Hi Ben, tested this on QGIS 2.6.0 and it works fine. Hopefully another can test this on 2.6.1. Is the MMQGIS plugin the latest version?

Comment: Thanks for checking, i have just downloaded 2.4 and I get the same error so I guess something has gone wrong my end. Have tried re-installing latest version of plugin but no luck, still doesn't work

Comment: Could it be a problem with your files as the error message contains "IndexError: list index out of range"? Maybe you can upload your files to Dropbox or something similar so others can test?

Comment: Thanks for the comment Joseph, you got me thinking objectively, I forgot to process the csv files first so that the rubbish had been removed from the top. Looks like its all working now.

Comment: Haha yes, it's funny how the most simplistic tasks can be so easily forgotten. Glad it's all working now buddy!